# IP has changed on Ruby on Rails Dev server and the cmd: cap staging deploy doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**Goal**: To have  "cap staging deploy"   work again.

**Problem:** The development server's IP was changed.

**Background:**
I develop on my personal PC/Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and push updates to the development/test server which is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS-Virtual Machine. I am using Rails 3 & Ruby 1.9.2. 
I have the git repository on the development server and I use SSH keys instead of passwords when I push updates or run: cap staging deploy.

I can successfully do: git push web_forms2_git_repo develop

When I run:  cap staging deploy ... I get these results:

```
  * executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * executing `multistage:ensure'
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://git@my-domain-name/home/git/web_forms2.git develop"
    command finished in 3381ms
  * executing "git clone -q ssh://git@my-domain-name/home/git/web_forms2.git /home/rails_192/apps/cals_web_forms/public/releases/20111220174923 && cd /home/rails_192/apps/cals_web_forms/public/releases/20111220174923 && git checkout -q -b deploy 5c2910f687480f136206e56ba73c268c7026df20 && (echo 5c2910f687480f136206e56ba73c268c7026df20 > /home/rails_192/apps/cals_web_forms/public/releases/20111220174923/REVISION)"
    servers: ["my-domain-name"]
    [my-domain-name] executing command
 ** [my-domain-name :: out] ssh: connect to host my-domain-name port 22: No route to host
 ** fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 3271ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/rails_192/apps/cals_web_forms/public/releases/20111220174923; true"
    servers: ["my-domain-name"]
    [my-domain-name] executing command
    command finished in 39ms
failed: "env PATH=/home/...
```

I did try to clone web_forms2 repository to my local PC but it didn't work and I will paste the results below:

Command: git clone ssh://git@my-domain-name/home/git/web_forms2.git

Results: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'web_forms2'.: Permission denied

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: did you forget to change IP in your `/etc/hosts` (if you use one)?

Comment: YES!!! That fixed it.  I've spent hours changing file permissions thinking that was the problem.  Now to put things back to the way they were before. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the IP of the server in your Capistrano config file (`config/deploy.rb`):

```
role :web, "71.19.150.118"   # replace this IP with the new IP or server address.
```

Keep in mind that if you use host names instead of IPs, @Sergei Tulentsev is right and you'll have to update your `/etc/hosts` file to reflect the change in the IP.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The first thing I did was change my IPs in the deploy scripts which did not solve all the problems. I didn't know that when the Server's IP changes I need to modify /etc/hosts. Thanks.